# how can we dont allow enum in mysql that doesn't be empty?

Tags: mysql, database, enums

I have an enum in mysql, i want that it doesn't get some thing except it's variables.
 when i pass it a strange variable, it doesn't accept it, but the last variable is cleared.
how can i do that?(sorry for my poor English!)
when some incorrect var inserts, it doesn't insert actually, but the last var is cleared!
i want keep it. how can i do that?

Comment: Have you set the field to `NOT NULL`? From my understadning it shoudl then set the value to the `DEFAULT` or the first enum value if there is no default set. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/enum.html

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling strict mode:

```
sql-mode = STRICT_ALL_TABLES
```

In your MySQL config.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_all_tables

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you switch the connection to [traditional mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_traditional):

```
SET @@SESSION.sql_mode='TRADITIONAL';
```

Among several other things, that prevents `ENUM` columns from accepting invalid values.